# CURL --resolve in node.js axios

Tags: node.js, curl, axios, resolve

Example request in plain CURL:

```
curl https://www.example.com --resolve www.example.com:443:127.0.0.1
```

Node.js code (missing the "resolve" feature):

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.example.com'
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

How can I pass the `resolve` option to Node.js Axios? I wasn't able to find any relevant information in their [readme](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Does it even have such functionality? If not, what NPM package does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios doesn't have this feature built in.

But you could try passing the host in the headers?

I've required https for the example to stop ssl issues.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const https = require('https')

const handler = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://www.example.com', {
        headers: { Host: '127.0.0.1:443' },
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }),
    })

    console.log(response)
}

handler()
```

Comment: Setting the Host header is just a part of what the --resolve does, I'm trying to figure out what it is but things that work with curl --resolve don't work just changing the Host header (in curl itself), much less in Node

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to setting the host name from the URL into the `Host` header, unless a `Host` header is explicitly specified, curl also uses the host name for the [TLS handshake](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7). That's why, when simply specifiying a `Host` header, curl won't behave the same way as when using a URL with that host value and specifying the address translation via `--resolve` - the value of the header *will* be used in the http request but won't be used for the TLS handshake. When a server receives a server name for which it doesn't have a certificate it will most often just break up the TLS handshake.

Axios uses node's built-in `http`/`https` modules. The instances of `http.Agent` and `https.Agent` to be used can be passed in the [config object](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) passed to `axios()` or `axios.create()`. (Those agent objects are the ones actually creating the TCP or TLS connections over which the http traffic will flow.) Those object will be initialized to default values if not present. You can specify an [`https.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#class-httpsagent) object constructed with [a config](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#new-agentoptions) where the `servername` field is filled with the value you want used instead of the DNS host name you want to connect to. Then, when you do the request, you need to use the DNS host name of the server you want to connect to in the URL and also add an explicit `Host` header with the same name used for configuring the agent as value to the request.

For example, with just the fields relevant for this discussion present (you still need to add at least http method and potentially other fields yourself), assuming your host has IP `192.168.14.32`, DNS name `server.some.place` and you want to use `virtual_server.some.other.place` for both TLS negotiation and `Host` header, the following two requests are equivalent:

```
axios({
    "url: "https://192.168.14.32/some/path",
    "httpsAgent": new https.Agent({
        "servername": "virtual_server.some.other.place"
    }),
    "headers": {
        "Host": "virtual_server.some.other.place"
    }
});

axios({
    "url: "https://server.some.place/some/path",
    "httpsAgent": new https.Agent({
        "servername": "virtual_server.some.other.place"
    }),
    "headers": {
        "Host": "virtual_server.some.other.place"
    }
});
```

Just one more note: you cannot manipulate the host header in browsers. The solution above will only work in node. Axios won't complain, but the request will go out with the host header reset to what you used in the URL by the browser, if you try this in a web page.