# CURL --resolve in node.js

Tags: node.js, axios

Can someone please provide **cURL --resolve** equivalent of below request in NodeJS-

```
curl http://www.example.com --resolve www.example.com:80:127.0.0.1
```

Output:

[image: cURL response Snapshot]

cURL works in terminal but I need to perform similar request using NodeJS for my application.

Followed article: [CURL --resolve in node.js axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128556/curl-resolve-in-node-js-axios) but this too gives me 404 Not Found error:

[image: NodeJS error Snapshot]

```
Debugger attached.
(node:33104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/home/anish/Desktop/SampleWeb/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/anish/Desktop/SampleWeb/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/anish/Desktop/SampleWeb/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:33104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:33104) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I have tried other stackoverflow questions but none of the solutions seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Do this properly, in any language (it even works in code not written by you like Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge). Edit you hosts file.

On Linux/Unix/Mac edit `/etc/hosts`..

On Windows edit `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Then add this line:

```
127.0.0.1    www.example.com
```

Now when you curl `www.example.com` or access it with node.js or point Google Chrome to `www.example.com` you will get 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Node has the concept of an 'Agent', which is an object you can pass to Axios, `node-fetch` or Node's built-in `HTTPS.request()`. Its purpose is to allow you to control how network requests are made.

The following would not work:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const spoof = 'www.example.com';
// This could also be a hostname like 'example.org':
const ip = '127.0.0.1';
 
axios.get(`https://${ip}`).then((body) => {
    console.log(body.data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

While this would make a request to `127.0.0.1`, the server running there wouldn't know you were requesting `www.example.com`. You need to specify that in two locations:

1. In the `Host` header.
2. If using HTTPS, in an Agent's `servername` field, for SNI. SNI is a value that indicates to the server what HTTPS certificate it should server and is sent before HTTP traffic, during the SSL/TLS set-up phase.

Normally, Node would take the domain name (the value of variable '`ip`' in this case) and send it as the SNI value (actually, in case of an IP-address, it should send `''`).

Do this as follows:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { Agent } from 'https';
const spoof = 'www.example.com';
const ip = '127.0.0.1';
     
const agent = new Agent({
    servername: spoof,
});
axios.get(`https://${ip}`, {
    headers: {
        Host: spoof,
    },
    httpsAgent: agent,
}).then((body) => {
    console.log(body.data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

If you are not using HTTPS, then you don't need to supply an Agent in this case.

---

Edit:
I mentioned that Agents are applicable to other HTTP request libraries, to illustrate: an example on how to do the same in `node-fetch`:

```js
fetch(`https://${ip}`, {
  headers: { Host: spoof },
  agent: new Agent({ servername: spoof }),
}).then(...)
```